# Android-Attach DB in SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite

my application download sqlite Database in Sdcard and then i want to attach downloaded db to my main db with this :

```
dbHelper.db.execSQL("attach database ? as userdbs", new String[]{unzipLocation+FileName});
```

it doesn't show error and it doesn't Work !!

---

### unzipLocation+FileName=/mnt/sdcard/MyFolder/TestDB.db

please help me Tnx

Comment: Did you check that this exact file name is readable from your app? What exactly do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: tnx for your comment...yes downloaded file is readable...this code was executed without error but nothing happened !

Comment: What do you expect to happen?